# Generating Array-based Graph With Java

Tags: java, graph, tree, generator

I need to generate a graph using integer arrays. Edges of the graphs are kept as edges[e][2] where e is the number of edges.
I need my graph to be connected, i.e. you should be able to traverse from all nodes to all nodes.

edges[0] = {0,5} means an edge connects node 0 and node 5.
Could you suggest an algorithm, please?

And please keep in mind that i will generate graphs with millions of nodes, so that it is better if algorithm complexity isn't too high.

Comment: What did you try so far? Where is the problem?

Comment: this is not an homework. a part of my academic study.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If each node is directly connected to each node, don't store all the edges ;)

If each node is reachable from each other node, but not necessarily directly, use an [adjacency matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix). That's the simplest way if you need to use integer arrays.

If the matrix is sparse, I would store it differently, though. The best encoding depends on what graph algorithms you want to use it for. [The wikipedia article on sparce matrices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix)) lists the major ones.